# How to get set differences and intersection with dplyr group piping

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~category, ~status, ~content,
  1, "control", "A",
  1, "control", "Z",
  1, "treated", "A",
  1, "treated", "Z",
  1, "control", "B",
  2, "control", "C",
  2, "control", "D",
  2, "treated", "C",
  2, "treated", "F"
) %>% 
  arrange(category, status, content)


dat
```

That looks like this:

```
> dat
  category status  content
     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
1        1 control A      
2        1 control B      
3        1 control Z      
4        1 treated A      
5        1 treated Z      
6        2 control C      
7        2 control D      
8        2 treated C      
9        2 treated F
```

What I want to do is to group it by `category` and then check the differences
and the intersection of the `content` between *control* and *treated*.

The output for differences for `control` only:

```
category    differences_control_only
1           B
2           D
```

The output for differences for `treated` only:

```
category    differences_treated_only
1           not_available
2           F
```

The output for the intersection between  `treated` and `control`:

```
  category      intersection
    1           A
    1           Z
    2           C
```

So at the end of the day, there will be 3 data frames as output.
How can I achieve that?

In this example, the grouping is only based on one column (`category`)
in real cases, grouping can be in multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get differences we can `group_by` `category` and `content` and select groups which has only one distinct `status`.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(category, content) %>% filter(n_distinct(status) == 1)

#  category status  content
#     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
#1        1 control B      
#2        2 control D      
#3        2 treated F
```

To get intersections we can `group_by` `category` and `content` and select groups which has more than one distinct `status` in it.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(category, content) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(status) >1) %>%
  distinct(category, content)

#  category content
#     <dbl> <chr>  
#1        1 A      
#2        1 Z      
#3        2 C
```

Comment: thanks but for differences, I'd like also to indicate the `status` of the content. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[,  .SD[uniqueN(status) > 1], .(category, content)]
```